# bash? - combining files into CSVs

Tags: bash, csv, text, data-manipulation

I know (see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/234208/combining-several-files-into-a-single-csv)) that you can use `paste` to combine multiple files into a `.csv` file if each file holds a column

i.e.. `paste -d "," column1.dat column2.dat column3.dat ... > myDat.csv` will result in

myDat.csv

```
column1,   column2,   column3, ...
c1-1,      c2-1,      c3-1,    ...
c1-2,      c2-2,      c3-2,    ...
...        ...        ...
```

(without the tabs. just inserted them to make it more readable)

What if I have multiple measurements, instead?

e.g.

`file1.dat` has format `<xvalue> <y1value>`

`file2.dat` has format `<xvalue> <y2avlue>`

`file3.dat` has format `<xvalue> <uvalue> <vvalue>`

and I ultimately want a csv like

```
<xvalue>, <y1value>, <y2value>, <empty column>, <uvalue>, <vvalue>
```

?

How do I combine the files now?

*Edit*

Note that although each file is sorted (or can be sorted if it's not), they don't necessarily contain the same xvalues on the same lines.

If a file doesn't have an xvalue that another file does have, its corresponding column entry should be blank.

(Actually, I think dropping the rows for xvalues that aren't present in all files should also work.)

Comment: Are each file sorted? Does it happen that file2.dat contains an `xvalue` that are not in file1.dat, or the opposite?

Comment: @andlrc yes to the sorted (and if not, it shouldn't be *too* hard to get them sorted before combining the files). and unfortunately, also yes to the ``xvalue`` disagreement,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here is my solution in Gnu awk which tries to lean towards being a more generic solution and handles that extra empty column with external tools. It is in Gnu awk since it uses multidimensional arrays but could probably easily be generalized to other awks as well.

The program joins fields expecting the first field of each file to be the key column. If it does not find a key to join to, it creates a new key and outputs nonexistent fields as empty when outputing (notice keys `x_3`, `x_4` and `x_5` below in data files).

First the data files:

```
$ cat file[123].dat             # 3 files, separated by empty lines for clarity
x_1 y1_1
x_2 y1_2
x_3 y1_3

x_1 y2_1
x_2 y2_2
x_4 y2_4

x_1 u_1 v_1
x_2 u_2 v_2
x_5 u_5 v_5
```

And the code:

```
$ cat program.awk
BEGIN { OFS=", " }
FNR==1 { f++ }                                # counter of files
{
    a[0][$1]=$1                               # reset the key for every record 
    for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)                        # for each non-key element
        a[f][$1]=a[f][$1] $i ( i==NF?"":OFS ) # combine them to array element
}
END {                                         # in the end
    for(i in a[0])                            # go thru every key
        for(j=0;j<=f;j++)                     # and all related array elements
            printf "%s%s", a[j][i], (j==f?ORS:OFS)
}                                             # output them, nonexistent will output empty
```

Usage and output:

```
$ awk -f program.awk \
file1.dat \
file2.dat \
<(grep -h . file[123].dat|cut -d\  -f 1|sort|uniq) \
file3.dat 
x_1, y1_1, y2_1, , u_1, v_1
x_2, y1_2, y2_2, , u_2, v_2
x_3, y1_3, , , 
x_4, , y2_4, , 
x_5, , , , u_5, v_5
```

The empty column after `file2.dat` will be generated with empty field created by gathering all the keys and inputing them as another "file" (using process substitution `<()`) to keep the program more generic:

```
$ grep -h . file[123].dat|cut -d\  -f 1|sort|uniq
x_1
x_2
x_3
x_4
x_5
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a process substitution?

```
paste -d, > myDat.csv \
  file1.dat \
  <(cut -d' ' -f2 file2.dat) \
  /dev/null \
  <(cut -d' ' -f2,3 file3.dat)
```

Comment: This assumes the files agree on the xvalues, doesn't it?

Comment: It does. If that's not the case then one would have to buffer multiply files in memory then lookup the correct line.

Comment: how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `paste` to combine all the files, and then use `awk` to only print the columns you want (including an empty column):

```
paste file1.dat file2.dat file3.dat | awk -v OFS=', ' '{print $1,$2,$4,"",$6,$7}'
```

Notice that columns `$3` and `$5` are excluded from the `awk` command because they are the same as column `$1` (i.e. they are all `<xvalue>`).

Comment: same issue as with andlrc's answer above: it assumes the files agree on the xvalues, which isn't necessarily the case.