# Merge many TSV files by first column

Tags: bash, perl, awk

I have many (dozens) TSV files in a directory that have only two columns, I want to merge all of them based on the first column value (both columns have headers that I need to maintain); if this value is present then it must add the value of the corresponding second column, and so on (see example). Files might have different number of lines and not ordered by first column, although this can be easily done with sort.

I have tried **join** but that works nicely for only two files. Can join be expanded for all files in a directory? I think **awk** might be a better solution, but my knowledge in awk is very very limited. Any ideas?

Here are the example of just three files:

```
S01.tsv

Accesion    S01  
AJ863320    1  
AM930424    1  
AY664038    2

S02.tsv

Accesion    S02  
AJ863320    2  
AM930424    1  
EU236327    1  
EU434346    2 

S03.tsv

Accesion    S03  
AJ863320    5  
EU236327    2  
EU434346    2
```

Outfile should be:

```
    Accesion    S01   S02   S03  
    AJ863320    1     2     5  
    AM930424    1     1
    AY664038    2  
    EU236327          1     2  
    EU434346          2     2
```

OK, thanks to James Brown I got this code working (I named it compile.awk) with a few glitches:

```
BEGIN { OFS="\t" }                            # tab separated columns
FNR==1 { f++ }                                # counter of files
{
    a[0][$1]=$1                               # reset the key for every record 
    for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)                        # for each non-key element
        a[f][$1]=a[f][$1] $i ( i==NF?"":OFS ) # combine them to array element
}
END {                                         # in the end
    for(i in a[0])                            # go thru every key
        for(j=0;j<=f;j++)                     # and all related array elements
            printf "%s%s", a[j][i], (j==f?ORS:OFS)
}                                             # output them, nonexistent will output empty
```

When I ran it with the actual files as

```
awk -f compile.awk 01.tsv 02.tsv 03.tsv
```

I get the output as:

```
LN854586.1.1236         1
JF128382.1.1303     1   
Accesion    S01 S02 S03
JN233077.1.1420 1       
HQ836180.1.1388     1   
KP718814.1.1338         1
JQ781640.1.1200         2
```

The first two lines do not belong there as the file should start with the headers (line three) of all files.
Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Can you show (in the question) what you have tried so far?

Comment: Basically join, tried some grep, and lots of searching for something similar, but nothing that I could implement or modify, maybe due to my lack of coding knowledge. Join does exactly what I want but work for only two files.

Comment: You can use the `program.awk` in the following link. Modify the `OFS` to your needs (`OFS="\t"` I'd assume). Also, output record order is random. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40373180/bash-combining-files-into-csvs/40408764#40408764

Comment: join with 3 files `join -a 1 -a 2 -e "" -o 0,1.2,2.2 S01.tsv S02.tsv | join -a 1 -a 2 -e "" -o 0,1.2,1.3,2.2 - S03.tsv` ..... [view join-multiple-files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10726471/join-multiple-files)

Comment: It doesn't output in order, you need to use `sort` for the output or control the scanning of `for`, see [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html). `awk -f compile.awk S*.tsv | sort`. Also, if your first field is so lengthy, tabs are not going to do it, you need `printf`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably tackle it something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @header; 
my %all_rows;
my %seen_cols;


#read STDIN or files specified as args. 
while ( <> ) {
   #detect a header row by keyword. 
   #can probably do this after 'open' but this way
   #means we can use <> and an arbitrary file list. 
   if ( m/^Accesion/ ) { 
      @header = split;       
      shift @header; #drop "accession" off the list so it's just S01,02,03 etc. 
      $seen_cols{$_}++ for @header; #keep track of uniques. 
   }
   else {
      #not a header row - split the row on whitespace.
      #can do /\t/ if that's not good enough, but it looks like it should be. 
      my ( $ID, @fields ) = split; 
      #use has slice to populate row.

      my %this_row;
      @this_row{@header} = @fields;

      #debugging
      print Dumper \%this_row; 

      #push each field onto the all rows hash. 
      foreach my $column ( @header ) {
         #append current to field, in case there's duplicates (no overwriting)
         $all_rows{$ID}{$column} .= $this_row{$column}; 
      }
   }
}

#print for debugging
print Dumper \%all_rows;
print Dumper \%seen_cols;

#grab list of column headings we've seen, and order them. 
my @cols_to_print = sort keys %seen_cols;

#print header row. 
print join "\t", "Accesion", @cols_to_print,"\n";
#iteate keys, and splice. 
foreach my $key ( sort keys %all_rows ) { 
    #print one row at a time.
    #map iterates all the columns, and gives the value or an empty string
    #if it's undefined. (prevents errors)
    print join "\t", $key, (map { $all_rows{$key}{$_} // '' } @cols_to_print),"\n"
}
```

Given your input - with debugging excluded - prints:

```
Accesion    S01 S02 S03 
AJ863320    1   2   5   
AM930424    1   1       
AY664038    2           
EU236327        1   2   
EU434346        2   2
```

Comment: This perl script work like a charm! I just comment (#) the debugging print lines for the final version, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a much briefer solution using eBay's fabulous [tsv-utils](https://github.com/eBay/tsv-utils), particularly [tsv-join](https://github.com/eBay/tsv-utils/blob/master/docs/tool_reference/tsv-join.md) command as follows:

```sh
FILES="S01.tsv S02.tsv S03.tsv"

tsv-select -H -f Accesion $FILES | tsv-uniq >out.tsv

for infile in $FILES
do
        tsv-join -H --filter-file $infile --key-fields 1 \
                    --append-fields 2  --write-all '' \
                    out.tsv >tmp.tsv;
        mv tmp.tsv out.tsv
done
```

Only very basic bash skills needed.

Answer (score 0):

I use `csvtool` for this and many csv/tsv tasks. (See [doc](https://colin.maudry.fr/csvtool-manual-page/).)

```bash
COMPARED=1 # Controls which columns are compared 
COPIED=2-3 # Controls which columns are copied into the new file
TSV_FILES=( a.tsv b.tsv c.tsv )

csvtool join $COMPARED $COPIED "${TSV_FILES[@]}" -u TAB -t TAB
```

The `COMPARED` and `COPIED` params can be a single number or a range of numbers or a comma-separated list of numbers.

The `-u TAB` and `-t TAB` params tell `csvtool` to use a TAB as the separator for the input and output, respectively.